# How to set kubernetes secrets outside a container section

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch, kibana, kustomize

I have a generated kubernetes secret like this as it is shown e.g. in argocd:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ES_GUEST_PASSWORD: ++++++++
  ES_GUEST_USERNAME: ++++++++
kind: Secret
```

I now want to use it as an input to a username and password setting for Kibana.
I know how to do it with env variables inside a container section but how do I do it outside a container?

In my case it is e.g. the configuration of the Elasticsearch/Kibana ECK Operator configuration:

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  version: 8.11.1
  count: 2
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elasticsearch
  config:
    xpack.security.authc.providers:
      anonymous.anonymous1:
        order: 0
        credentials:
          username: ES_GUEST_USERNAME
          password: ES_GUEST_PASSWORD
      basic.basic1:
        order: 1
```

In this case ES_GUEST_USERNAME and ES_GUEST_PASSWORD are just used as plain text and not replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't", unless the the API schema supports something like the `envFrom`/`valueFrom` attributes available in a Pod spec.

The longer answer is that you can use a [Mutating Admission Webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) to do pretty much anything you want, including injecting secrets into a resource at creation time. You could write your own, but there are existing implementations that can do this sort of thing like. For exapmle, [Bank Vault](https://bank-vaults.dev/) uses this technique to inject secrets from a Hashicorp Vault instance. The [patch operator](https://github.com/redhat-cop/patch-operator) is a general tool for performing these sorts of transformations.